# How to display a column based on a condition that meets true for corresponding column in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is my data.frame,it contains NA in bonus and increment.

```
df
name salary bonus increment(%)
AK   22200  120   2
BK   55000   34   .1
JK   12000  400   3
VK   3400   350   15
DK   5699    NA    NA

df = structure(list(name = c("AK", "BK", "JK", "VK", "DK"), salary = c(22200L, 
55000L, 12000L, 3400L, 5699L), bonus = c(120L, 34L, 400L, 350L, 
NA), `increment(%)` = c(2, 0.1, 3, 15, NA)), .Names = c("name", 
"salary", "bonus", "increment(%)"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

basically, I want to store the name of those persons who have got a max salary, max bonus and max increment.

what i have tried is below

```
df[sapply(df[,2:4],function(x) which.max(x)),1]
output: [1] "BK" "JK" "VK"
```

But need a robust way which can give the same output as above command but takes care of NA as well. Also I am not sure using `,1` is good thing to display the name column.

Comment: Re your last sentence, yeah, better to use `df[w, "name"]` or `df$name[w]` or `df[["name"]][w]`, I think.

Comment: Thanks @Frank for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
sapply(df[,2:4], function(x) df[which(x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE)),'name'])
```

returns:

```
salary     bonus     increment(%) 
"BK"       "JK"      "VK"
```

Comment: Yes JanLauGe, this one is the exact the thing i was looking for. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col` on transposed dataframe, to get maximum for each row. `max.col` doesn't handle `NA`'s we can replace them with 0.

```
df$name[max.col(t(replace(df, is.na(df), 0))[-1, ])]

#[1] "BK" "JK" "VK"
```